# Shortest distance between points on a toroidally wrapped (x- and y- wrapping) map?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, math, geometry, distance

I have a toroidal-ish Euclidean-ish map.  That is the surface is a flat, Euclidean rectangle, but when a point moves to the right boundary, it will appear at the left boundary (at the same y value), given by x_new = x_old % width

Basically, points are plotted based on: * *see edit*

```
(x_new, y_new) = ( x_old % width, y_old % height)
```

Think Pac Man -- walking off one edge of the screen will make you appear on the opposite edge.

What's the best way to calculate the shortest distance between two points?  The typical implementation suggests a large distance for points on opposite corners of the map, when in reality, the real wrapped distance is very close.

The best way I can think of is calculating Classical Delta X and Wrapped Delta X, and Classical Delta Y and Wrapped Delta Y, and using the lower of each pair in the Sqrt(x^2+y^2) distance formula.

But that would involve many checks, calculations, operations -- some that I feel might be unnecessary.

Is there a better way?

---

*edit*

When an object moves, it moves to position (x_old,y_old), runs it through the above formula, and stores (x_new, y_new) as its position.  The above formula was only added to clarify what happens when objects move across the boundary; in reality, only one (x,y) pair is stored in each object at a time.

Comment: So your geometry is the same as in Asteroids? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asteroids_(video_game)

Comment: By the way, in physics-speak we'd say you're using 2D periodic boundary conditions. It is in fact equivalent (isomorphic I think) to the surface of a torus.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> The best way I can think of is calculating Classical Delta X and Wrapped Delta X, and Classical Delta Y and Wrapped Delta Y, and using the lower of each pair in the Sqrt(x^2+y^2) distance formula.

That's it, I don't think there is any quicker way. But it's not too hard of a computation; you could do something like

```
dx = abs(x1 - x2);
if (dx > width/2)
  dx = width - dx;
// again with x -> y and width -> height
```

(I trust you can translate that into your preferred language)

Comment: heh, same second, same idea :)

Comment: so many good ideas; this one was simply first.  I liked that you can do a quick comparism to width/2 instead of calculating both deltas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The shortest distance between two points in a periodic domain can be computed as follows without using any loops.

```
    dx = x2-x1
    dx = dx - x_width*ANINT(dx/x_width)
```

This will give a signed shortest distance. ANINT is an intrinsic FORTRAN function such that ANINT(x) gives the nearest whole number whose *magnitude* is less than abs(x)+0.5, with the same sign as x. For eg., ANINT(0.51)=1.0 , ANINT(-0.51)=-1.0 , etc. Similar functions exist for other languages.

Comment: nice solution but you need to take the ABS of the result to avoid negative answers in some cases

Answer (score 3):

To find the smallest delta in the `a`-axis for new coordinates with values `a1` and `a2`, where `aBoundary`is the boundary on the `a`-axis:

```
def delta(a1, a2, aBoundary):
  return min(abs(a2 - a1), abs(a2 + aBoundary - a1))
```

So if you have two points with new coordinates `x1,y1` and `x2,y2`, you can just do:

```
sumOfSquares(delta(x1,x2,width), delta(y1,y2,height))
```

This is effectively what you suggest, but I wouldn't say it's "many checks, calculations and operations".

Comment: As-is, that delta function only seems to work with a1>a2. When a1<a2, the sign on aBoundary has to flip. Change that second min argument to: `abs(abs(a2 - a1) - aBoundary)` to cover both cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
(delta_x, delta_y)= 
     (min(width - abs(x_new - x_new), abs(x_new - x_old)), 
      min(height - abs(y_new - y_old), abs(y_new - y_old)))
```

Comment: Do you realize that abs(x_old - x_new) is equivalent to abs(x_new - x_old)?

Answer (score 0):

No distance can be greater than width/2 and height/2. If you get a difference (X1-X2) greater than width/2, substract width/2 to get the short-cut distance. Calculate distance then as usual.

Comment: Actually wouldn't you want to subtract from the width? e.g. if X1-X2 == 0.55*width you should get 0.45*width

Comment: Guess you're right. You could subtract whole width, though.. whatever

Answer (score 0):

Man I did something WAY different...

there's a little extra fuctionality in here but the core is the distance on a wrapped screen...

```
from math import sqrt
import pytweening

class ClosestPoint_WD(object):
def __init__(self, screen_size, point_from, point_to):
    self._width = screen_size[0]
    self._height = screen_size[1]
    self._point_from = point_from
    self._point_to = point_to
    self._points = {}
    self._path = []

def __str__(self):
    value = "The dictionary:" + '\n'
    for point in self._points:
        value = value + str(point) + ":" + str(self._points[point]) + '\n'

    return value

def distance(self, pos0, pos1):
    dx = pos1[0] - pos0[0]
    dy = pos1[1] - pos0[1]
    dz = sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2)

    return dz

def add_point_to_dict(self, x, y):
    point = x, y
    self._points[point] = 0

def gen_points(self):
    max_x = self._width * 1.5 - 1
    max_y = self._height * 1.5 - 1

    # point 1, original point
    self.add_point_to_dict(self._point_to[0], self._point_to[1])

    # add the second point: x-shifted
    if self._point_to[0] + self._width <= max_x:
        self.add_point_to_dict(self._point_to[0] + self._width, self._point_to[1])
    else:
        self.add_point_to_dict(self._point_to[0] - self._width, self._point_to[1])

    # add the third point: y-shifted
    if self._point_to[1] + self._height <= max_y:
        self.add_point_to_dict(self._point_to[0], self._point_to[1] + self._height)
    else:
        self.add_point_to_dict(self._point_to[0], self._point_to[1] - self._height)

    # add the fourth point: diagonally shifted
    if self._point_to[0] + self._width <= max_x:
        if self._point_to[1] + self._height <= max_y:
            self.add_point_to_dict(self._point_to[0] + self._width, self._point_to[1] + self._height)
        else:
            self.add_point_to_dict(self._point_to[0] + self._width, self._point_to[1] - self._height)
    else:
        if self._point_to[1] + self._height <= max_y:
            self.add_point_to_dict(self._point_to[0] - self._width, self._point_to[1] + self._height)
        else:
            self.add_point_to_dict(self._point_to[0] - self._width, self._point_to[1] - self._height)

def calc_point_distances(self):
    for point in self._points:
        self._points[point] = self.distance(self._point_from, point)

def closest_point(self):
    d = self._points
    return min(d, key=d.get)

def update(self, cur_pos, target):
    self._point_from = cur_pos
    self._point_to = target
    self._points = {}
    self.gen_points()
    self.calc_point_distances()
    self.shortest_path()

def shortest_path(self):
    path = pytweening.getLine(self._point_from[0], self._point_from[1], self.closest_point()[0], self.closest_point()[1])
    #path = pytweening.getLine((self._point_from)
    ret_path = []

    for point in path:
        ret_path.append((point[0] % self._width, point[1] % self._height))

    self._path = ret_path
    return self._path
```

Comment: your answer would be more useful if you explained HOW you calculate the distance, and why it's a good method (since the OP is asking for "the best method").  Dropping a chunk of code with no explanation is generally considered to be a poor quality answer.

Comment: Good point. I was reacting to elegance of other's solutions compared to mine.

What I do is given two points, I want to know which route is the quickest to the second point from the first and how to get there. The trick wasn't figuring out which point was closest, the trick was doing that in a way that returned the 'coordinates' of that point. I projected the point into a buffer 1/2 the size of the screen in each direction, then calculated the distance to each one and returned the shortest of those. I then created a path to move my initial point along to get to it.

Answer (score -1):

you can't use the “abs” function with the mod operator!

```
xd =(x1-x2+Width)%Width
yd=(y1-y2+Height)%Height
D=sqrt(xd^2+yd^2)
```